# why grep only allows me to search whole words

Tags: grep

I'm trying to grep some code for any code that matches 'enforce' and the following works and shows results:

```
grep --include=\*.rb -rnw . -e enforce
```

yet the following gives no results:

```
grep --include=\*.rb -rnw . -e enforc
```

How do I grep for anything that contains 'enforc'?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Remove `w` from the options:

```
grep --include=\*.rb -rn . -e enforc
```

> **-w, --word-regexp**
>   Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words.  The test is that the matching substring must either be
>   at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a  non-word  constituent
>                 character.  Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character. 
>   Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.

Comment: Oh thanks, that was stupid of me, I just copied code without looking at what it did.

Comment: @simonzack Any time you see `-blahblah` that means it's doing _something_ (and, furthermore, something that isn't the default) so, yeah, that's the first thing to check.